# Is it statistically correct to go for Poisson regression for count data (number of insects) but data follows normal distribution

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, poisson-regression

I have weekly observations of the number of insects (`1 1   5   8   13  7   8   8   9   8   2   2   1   1   1   1   0   0`). My question is: even though the data is count data, it doesn't follow the Poisson distribution (as checked by means of K-S test), it mostly follows the Normal distribution.  My question is: shall I go for regular least squares-based regression or shall I go for Poisson regression?

It's time series data, 5 years, each year has data for the same 18 weeks, so there are 18*5= 90 data points.

```
std. weeks 9th week 
(2011) 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27‌​ 28 29 30 31 32 33 3‌​4 35 36 9
(2012) 9 10‌​ 11 12 13 14 15 16 1‌​7 18 19 20 21 22 23 ‌​24 25 26 27 28 29 30‌​ 31 32 33 34 35 36 9‌​
(2015) 10 11 12 13 1‌​4 15 16 17 18 19 20 ‌​21 22 23 24 25 26 27‌​ 28 29 30 31 32 33 3‌​4 35 36 
INSECT COUNT 
3 4 4 6 7 9 8 9 8 7 6 6 5 4 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 ‌​0 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 9 8‌​ 6 6 6 5 3 2 1 1 1 1‌​ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4‌​ 4 7 9 8 9 8 7 6 6 5‌​ 4 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1‌​ 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3‌​ 4 7 7 8 8 7 6 6 5 4‌​ 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0‌​ 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 3 3 6‌​ 9 10 9 7 6 5 6 4 3 ‌​2 1 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 0 ‌​0 0 0 0
(36 week 2015)
```

I mentioned data from 2011 (9th week to 36th week) - 2015 (9th week to 36th week) and all the insects count data from 2011 to 2015 (respective weeks) in addition to this respective week wise weather parameters also there (around 8 variables) 
These are my weather parameters. Can anyone suggest what I should do?

```
**Rain Fall**   82.1    69.3    63.1    41.3    30.7    23.5    22.1    72.1    23.1    0   0   0   0   3.2 2.7 0   0   0   0   43.4    57.8    38.4    16.4    30.9    16.7    18  112.2   9.5 0   6.4 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   48.2    69.5    28.6    37.4    32.3    150.3   3.2 0   4.6 12.2    83.9    44  17  0   0   0   0   0   0   4.6 46  142.7   42.4    14  6.5 34.9    11  13.7    2.1 0   50.7    0   6.2 0   0   0   0   0   54  81.2    18.6    116.3   49.5    42.2    0   0   11.9    0   0   0   0   0   23  0   0   0   0
**MAX Temperature** 33.8    33.9    33.7    33.9    34  36  33.1    31.3    33.8    35.3    35.4    33.3    33.5    32.1    31.1    30.1    29.6    28.7    27.6    32.1    32.2    32  32.2    32.3    34.3    31.4    29.6    32.1    33.6    33.7    31.6    31.8    30.4    29.4    28.4    27.9    27  25.9    32.2    32.5    32.5    31.8    32.1    28.7    32.5    33.7    31.6    31.6    28.8    29.1    26.7    29.6    289.6   27.7    26.2    26.7    26.4    33.3    32.8    32.9    23.6    35.1    33  32.7    31.9    33.3    33.4    32.2    31.2    29.8    29.8    30.4    31.4    27.5    26.9    27.8    33.2    31.6    34  32.7    33.2    33.4    34.6    24.6    31.1    33.3    34  33.5    33  32.1    28  30.6    30.4    28.7    28.4
**MIN Temperature** 26  25.6    25.3    28.2    25.2    26.9    25  24  24.5    23.1    23.1    20.7    19  16.6    15.4    14.4    12.2    10.5    9.8 26.9    26.5    26.2    29.1    26.1    27.8    25.9    24.9    25.4    24  24  21.6    19.9    17.5    16.3    15.3    13.1    11.4    10.7    26.3    25.5    26  25.7    26.2    25.7    25.3    26.9    25.3    25.5    24.3    23.8    21.1    21.1    17.3    15.5    11.5    25  13.7    26.6    27.7    26.4    27.6    27.5    27.1    26.4    25.8    26  24.3    24.2    24  19.8    19.2    18  16.3    13.6    11  11.9    26.4    25.4    26.7    27.1    25.7    26.7    26.3    27.5    26.9    23.8    22.8    22  21.8    19  16.6    18.6    16.6    16.2    17.2
**MAX R H** 90.8    90.8    88.8    87.8    88.8    90.8    90.8    95.8    91.8    83.8    86.8    87.8    86.8    85.8    88.8    89.8    91.8    91.8    88.8    89  89  87  86  87  89  89  94  90  82  85  86  85  84  87  88  90  90  87  86  84  91  88  83  92  80  85  81  86  93  84  92  88  80  84  90  89  87  82  87  87  86  77  84  85  91  87  85  79  88  88  83  85  86  83  89  84  85  86  85  89  87  90  80  86  87  80  83  82  79  88  93  89  89  90  86
**MIN R H** 78.2    71.2    73.2    71.2    70.2    65.2    72.2    79.2    65.2    51.2    34.2    53.2    49.2    51.2    46.2    48.2    54.2    58.2    32.2    81  74  76  74  73  68  75  82  68  54  37  56  52  54  49  51  57  61  35  77  75  76  80  74  87  66  66  76  77  85  78  80  72  76  60  48  41  46  65  74  74  79  60  71  69  80  72  56  64  68  69  58  41  39  37  36  49  64  69  67  77  72  74  59  64  66  54  51  52  59  56  82  49  40  49  53
**Sun shine  Hr**   4.7 4.8 7.5 4.9 5.2 3.1 8.3 5.5 3.8 3.9 2.7 2.9 1.9 2   2   2.7 1.7 2.4 3   3.8 3.9 6.6 4   4.3 2.2 7.4 4.6 2.9 3   1.8 2   1   1.1 1.1 1.8 0.8 1.5 2.1 6.6 5.8 3.7 2.4 5.3 3   4.2 1.9 5.2 2.8 5.9 5.5 1.5 2.2 1.6 0.6 1.2 1   1.9 2.4 5.4 5.1 5.4 4   7.2 5   1.8 1.6 3.6 1.2 3.7 1.6 0.8 1.2 1.3 1.9 1.3 1   5   5   1.9 4.2 6.4 3   4   3.1 5   3.4 1.3 1.8 1.5 0.3 1.4 0.8 1.8 0.7 1.1
**wind speed**  5.1 4.2 6.3 4.2 4.7 7.7 5.6 3.2 5.1 9.7 7.9 8.9 8.6 8.7 7.4 7.2 7.7 8.3 8.6 4.4 3.5 5.6 3.5 4   7   4.9 2.5 4.4 9   7.2 8.2 7.9 8   6.7 6.5 7   7.6 7.9 5.8 6.7 4.6 6.9 6.9 1.5 7.6 7.2 8   6.8 3.9 6.5 4.2 8.9 7.8 7.6 7.9 8.5 8.1 4.8 5.7 4.1 2.4 6.7 5.3 6   4   5.2 9.3 7.2 6.1 6.8 6.8 6.8 7.2 5.4 7.2 7.3 6.2 4.8 5.2 6   5.9 4.5 8.8 7.3 6.9 8.8 9   8.6 8   8.3 5.2 5.7 7.6 4.4 4.3
**evoptrpn**    3.8 4.3 4.8 4.5 4.4 5.1 4.4 3.9 4.2 4.3 4.3 4.3 3.2 3.1 2.9 2.8 2.4 2.4 2.5 3.1 3.6 4.1 3.8 3.7 4.4 3.7 3.2 3.5 3.6 3.6 3.6 2.5 2.4 2.2 2.1 1.7 1.7 1.8 4.3 4.3 4.1 3.8 4.2 2.5 3.7 3.7 3.9 2.9 3.3 2.6 1.7 2.9 2.3 1.6 1.5 1.8 1.6 3.3 4.4 3.3 2.8 4.4 4.6 3   3.1 3.4 4.1 3.1 2.6 1.7 1.8 2.4 2.3 2   1.7 1.9 5.1 1.4 4.2 4.4 4.9 3.6 4.2 3.7 4.3 3.2 3   3.2 3.1 2.7 2   2.6 2.5 1.4 2.1
```

Comment: The raw data (indicating the marginal distribution of the DV) are not assumed to be distributed as a Poisson for a Poisson regression. The *conditional* distribution of the DV is assumed to be Poisson.  Don't waste time over assumptions that aren't anything to do with your actual model.

Comment: Can you please spell out lsd?

Comment: From the one example you give and the description of count data it is utterly implausible that you have normally distributed data. But as @Glen_b points out, the exact marginal distribution is typically not crucial.

Comment: thank you all for you response. sir, if possible please elaborate little bit,                                 (i means to say lsd- least squared estimation).  i have same pattern every season and i have 130 data points. actually i interested to predict the occurrence of given insects for the given weather parameters (i have 7 independent variable) am Entomology student, so give me bit elaboration your ideas what i have to do? am very thankful to you.

Comment: Those are counts in each of 18 consecutive weeks? As in you have a *time series* of counts?

Comment: Can you post your data (for example, a link to some data hosting service) so we can have a look?

Comment: I agree with @kjetilbhalvorsen about posting the data.  It's hard to give advice without having details about the data you actually have

Comment: Ha sir yes,  its time series data, 5 years, each year same week data around 18 weeks, 18*5= 90 data points.

Comment: std. weeks 9th week (2011) 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 9(2012) 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 9(2015) 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
INSECT COUNT 3 4 4 6 7 9 8 9 8 7 6 6 5 4 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 11 9 8 6 6 6 5 3 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 4 7 9 8 9 8 7 6 6 5 4 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 4 7 7 8 8 7 6 6 5 4 3 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 3 3 6 9 10 9 7 6 5 6 4 3 2 1 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0(36 week 2015)

Comment: i mentioned data from 2011 (9th week to 36th week) - 2015 (9th week to 36th week) and all the insects count data from 2011 to 2015 (respective weeks) in addition to this respective week wise weather parameters also there (around 8 variables)

Comment: For the record: You should have aded this information as an edit to the originalpost (OP). For now I do that for you!  Please also add the weather parameters!